# Como puedo bloquear los dias anteriores del calendario en un input type date?

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas estoy en colombia y quiero poder desactivar los dias anteriores al actual el problema es que con el toisostring me lo muestra 5 horas despues

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este no es un buen ejemplo porque el `input` me da la fetcha correcta, pero aquí `obtenerFecha` agrega o resta la diferencia horaria.

```js
function obtenerFecha(event) {
  const fetcha = new Date(event.target.value);
  const timeoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  const parsed = Date.parse(fetcha);
  const nuevaFetcha = new Date(parsed + timeoffset);
  const iso = nuevaFetcha.toISOString();
  console.log(fetcha, nuevaFetcha, iso);
}
```

```html
<input id="fetcha" type="date" onchange="obtenerFecha(event)" />
```